# Changing selection color of features in QGIS 3.20

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, features, select, color

In QGIS 3.20.1 when I select a feature of any polygon it turns white unlike the older versions that were yellow.

[image]

Is it possible to change this selection color using a simple way?

*Note:* I do not have administrator privileges on my machine.

OBS 2: Even if I followed the answer I can't solve the problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/170184/128665) help? The selection colour in the general settings can be overridden in the Project Properties (`Ctrl+Shift+P`). You might want to check what colour it is there too.

Comment: Did you try creating a new, empty project and create a new layer from scratch? Does the problem persist?

Comment: Yes, I created a new profile in a new project, but the selection with the white color persists

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that it is some profile file that has corrupted, you can try to create a new profile, which comes with the default settings.

[image]

Comment: I created a new profile, made the selection color change, but still the same.